# I upgraded my .RDLC from VS 2008 to VS 2010 and now the Page is Blank when I run the report

Tags: reporting-services, upgrade, ssrs-2008

At first the issue I had was easily found, then I added the Script Manager as suggested and that caused the error to go away.  Now, it just doesn't render.

It's a very simple report.  When I don't "hide" the report at first, it will render, but time out, so I know it will work.  It seems like I'm running into some type of Asynch Issue moving from SSRS 2008 and SSRS 2010.  I have tried various properties with an Update Panel and the Async Rendering, and this did not help.

Here is my basic Code

```
    <rsweb:ReportViewer ID="ReportViewer2" runat="server" Font-Names="Verdana" Visible="false"
        Font-Size="8pt" Height="564px" Width="1055px" >
        <LocalReport ReportPath="Reports/SingleUK.rdlc">

            <DataSources>
                <rsweb:ReportDataSource DataSourceId="MainSqlDataSource" Name="DataSet1" />
            </DataSources>
        </LocalReport>
    </rsweb:ReportViewer>



<asp:SqlDataSource ID="MainSqlDataSource" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:AncillaryProductionConnectionString %>" 
    SelectCommand="packsheets.procUKPacksheets" 
    SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure" 
    onselecting="MainSqlDataSource_Selecting">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:FormParameter Type="Int32" DefaultValue="" 
            FormField="StatusDropDownList" Name="Status" />
        <asp:FormParameter Type="Int32" DefaultValue="" FormField="HoldDropDownList" 
            Name="Hold" />
        <asp:FormParameter Type="Int32" DefaultValue="0" 
            FormField="NoteCategoryDropDownList" Name="Notes" />
        <asp:FormParameter Type="Int32" DefaultValue="0" 
            FormField="ShippingGroupDropDownList" Name="ShMeth" />
        <asp:Parameter Direction="ReturnValue" Name="RETURN_VALUE" Type="Int32" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

and the Code Behind

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        //{
        //    this.ReportViewer2.Visible = false;
        //}
    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.ReportViewer2.Visible = true;
        this.ReportViewer2.LocalReport.Refresh();

    }

    protected void MainSqlDataSource_Selecting(object sender, SqlDataSourceSelectingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Command.Parameters["@Status"].Value == null)
        {
            e.Command.Parameters["@Status"].Value = DBNull.Value;
        }
        if (e.Command.Parameters["@Hold"].Value == null)
        {
            e.Command.Parameters["@Hold"].Value = DBNull.Value;
        }
    }
}
```

Does anyone have any idea on what else I could try?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: By "upgraded" do you mean you ran it through Visual Studio's 2010 upgrade wizard?  Or did you rewrite the report using the version of SSRS included in Visual Studio 2010?

Answer (score 0):

SSRS reports written in Visual Studio are a bit like Vegas.  What happens in that version of Visual Studio stays in that version of Visual Studio.

Unfortunately, to upgrade from VS 2008 to VS 2010, you'd need to rewrite your .rdlc report from scratch.  (The same goes for VS 2005 to VS 2008.)

Here's a related MSDN forum post on the subject:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/sqlreportingservices/thread/9a7a78a0-bf5c-458a-9cb0-bc82004501f7

Hope this helps,

--Dubs

Comment: "SSRS reports written in Visual Studio are a bit like Vegas" - only with less beer and strippers.